# Mongodb-PHP: File download doesnt download expected file

Tags: php

I am using mongodb with php. I have agreement download option on which when user clicks user get the agreemment downloaded. On click i have navigated to script where file download code in php is there
code is

```
$mongoDbA = $mongoDb->findOne(array("agency_id" => new MongoId($_GET['id'])));
$filename = '../../images/upload/'.$mongoDbA['file'];

if (file_exists($filename)) 
{
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
exit;
}
```

I have allowed to upload only pdf files so only pdf files are there in database

When i click then it gives me error & gives me white colored file that has no extension & size is 1 kb hardly....what is happening???

Comment: Please check php error_log. The file you download is empty due to php error. Have you tried opening "white colored" file with notebook?

Comment: no. i tried renaming with .pdf the white file then it shows "cannot open file"...

Comment: Open it with notepad if it is a php error it probably is thrown in there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filename = './images/upload/'.$mongoDbA['file'];

    $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
    $sendname = $fileinfo['filename'] . '.' . $fileinfo['extension'];

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$sendname"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
```

Comment: does it have anything to do with application.pdf & text/pdf ??

Comment: yes see also http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm